# Instantiating classes with params in singleton factory

Tags: php, singleton

I have a class that produces singleton classes. *(Note that this is overly simplified code for the purpose of this question, for example it doesn't check that the filepath exists)*

```
class Singleton
{
   public function Load($classname, $params)
   {
      $filepath = 'classes/'.$classname.'.php';
      require_once($filepath);
      return $classname();
   }

}
```

Now say that I wanted to pass an array of parameters that can vary in size to the constructor of the class being created. What is the best way to do this? I envision something along the lines of `call_user_func_array` but for classes?

Comment: Any reason you are using a Singleton and not just a static method?

Comment: You might want to read up on [PHP's autoloading functionality](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), which duplicates what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @jacob, because the parameters passed to the classes may change on a case by case basis. For example one class that gets loaded is a MySqlConnection class that has connection details passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve some interesting results with the use of [PHP's Reflection library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

```
function Load( $class, $args )
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass( $class );
    $object = $reflection->newInstanceArgs( $args );
    return $object;
}
```

This is simplified and implies use of the `__autoload` function, nor does it check for namespaces if you use them, plus it'll create a new instance of the class every time you call it, so you'll need to implement an array of objects to keep track of which ones you've created already, etc...

And for basic documentation: `$class` is a string with the name of the class you're wishing to instantiate, and `$args` is an array of arguments that you'll pass to the `__construct( )` method.

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but why not just load them into the constructor? ie return `$classname($params)`; with your constructor set up like `__construct($params = false).` You can then check if params is passed or not, making your constructor parameters optional...

This does mean all your classes need to have the same constructor though.

```
    class Foo {

        public function __construct($params = false) {
            if($params === false) 
                echo 'not passed';
            else 
                print_r($params);
        }
    }

$class = 'Foo';
$foo = new $class(array('one', 'two'));
$foo2 = new $class();
```

outputs:
Array ( [0] => one [1] => two ) 
not passed

Comment: Thanks Jorg. I did initally consider this, but was wondering if there was a more elegant way to achieve it.

Comment: Sorry mate, can't really think of anything other than this, session variables, or setting up another class that holds all your variables... But those solutions don't sound more elegant to me at all :p